# Multiple applications using mic suddenly unable to capture mic sounds

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

*First of all I don't know if I'm using the correct platform here so please tell me if I am.*

I'm having trouble figuring out why my microphone (steelseries H wireless headset) "broke".
I'm unable to use my mic on discord, league and steam calls, while I can still hear other people, they can't hear me.

Using facebook messenger call everyone can hear me. Playing back my mic sound with microphone properties I can hear myself too.

Yet trying the play back my mic sound on discord, still nothing.

I tried using another usb port, updating drivers, reinstalling programs, trying out every setting but nothing seems to work.

**EDIT:**
Tried using secondary headset I had laying around and had exact the same problems.

Comment: Can you get ahold of another mic to try?  I had one of my headsets just suddenly go bad like that.  One day it worked, next day nobody could hear me even though I could hear them.  Other headsets worked just fine, so appears my mic just suddenly broke...

Comment: I'll try this but my mic does still work according to facebook messenger & windows itself

Comment: Different headset, same problems.

Comment: As you connect the microphone to the USB port, is the device installed correctly and visible in Device Manager and recording device/endpoint lists?

If you open Windows Sound Settings and scroll down to "Test your microphone", does input level indicator moving when you speak into the mic?

In Windows Settings - Privacy - Microphone, is microphone access enabled?

Comment: Privacy settings was disabled and fixed my problem -although I do not recall changing it-. Strange that facebook was still allowed